# Dafny suggests that multiplying odd numbers doesn't always give an odd result

Tags: dafny

I have a sequence of numbers, and perform an operations based on oddity of the number. It ends up boiling down to having only odd numbers in one variable, which leads to invariant failing because it insists that the number is not odd.

To check it, I made this. In here, whenever a number is odd, it tries to multiply it. Unless I overlooked something, multiplying two odd numbers should always result in another odd number (since it should be `(m+1)*(n+1)`). While dafny acknowledges the number being odd, it calls the multiplication an assert violation.

```
if A[i]%2 == 0 {
  ... // not important skip for now
} else {
  assert A[i]%2 == 1;
  assert (A[i] * A[i])%2 == 1;
  ... // do something with it, lets say multiply
}
```

Is there a way of solving this?
The array itself contains integers (both even and odd).
(this is an operation performed within while cycle).

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying you get an assertion violation on the second assert? That would mean Dafny could not prove that the result was odd. Could you share a complete example that demonstrates your error, perhaps via [rise4fun](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny)?

Comment: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/q7ww

Comment: Or here is one with a similiar structure to what I did, when I tried to move it out and prove it as a separate function just to isolate side-effects. https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/Ritb

Comment: aha, I see what you mean now. unfortunately, I don't know a good answer for you. Dafny struggles to reason about multiplication, division, and modulo. for some inspiration, you might find [this library](https://github.com/microsoft/Ironclad/tree/master/ironfleet/src/Dafny/Libraries/Math) useful

Answer (score 0):

We'd like to show the following lemma.

```
lemma odd_mul_odd(a: int, b: int)
requires a % 2 == 1
requires b % 2 == 1
ensures (a * b) % 2 == 1
```

Having done a few math proofs in Dafny, I've learned that one axiom it can prove easily is `a == (a/b)*b + (a%b)`.

Therefore, I would attempt a proof based on the following logic:

- Write a=2x+1 for some x
- Write b=2y+1 for some y
- Write (a*b)=4xy + 2x + 2y + 1 = 2(2xy + x + y) + 1
- Therefore (a*b)%2 == 1

Here it is in Dafny,

```
lemma odd_mul_odd(a: int, b: int)
requires a % 2 == 1
requires b % 2 == 1
ensures (a * b) % 2 == 1
{
  var x := a / 2;
  var y := b / 2;

  calc {
    a * b;
    {   
      assert a == 2*x + 1;
      assert b == 2*y + 1;
    }   
    (2*x + 1) * (2*y + 1); 
    4*x*y + 2*x + 2*y + 1;
    2*(2*x*y + x + y) + 1;
  }

  calc {
    (a * b) % 2;
    (2*(2*x*y + x + y) + 1) % 2;
    1;  
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, these sorts of mathematical proofs are a bit of a pain-point in Dafny. My only advice is to make liberal use of the `calc` statement and take things one step at a time.